# Extended WPF Toolkit - Styling the RichTextBox with FormatBar causes exception

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, attached-properties

I'm trying to style the Extended WPF Toolkit RichTextBox like so:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type tk:RichTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="SpellCheck.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>   
    <Setter Property="tk:RichTextBoxFormatBarManager.FormatBar" Value="{x:Type tk:RichTextBoxFormatBar}"/>
</Style>
```

However at runtime it fails with a ArgumentNullException saying: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: property".

What could be causing this behaviour?

**EDIT 1**
I also tried this syntax:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type tk:RichTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="SpellCheck.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="tk:RichTextBoxFormatBarManager.FormatBar">
        <Setter.Value>
            <tk:RichTextBoxFormatBar />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Unfortunately it gave me the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

Value is expecting an instance not a Type. Please try

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type tk:RichTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="SpellCheck.IsEnabled" Value="True" />   
    <Setter Property="tk:RichTextBoxFormatBarManager.FormatBar">
        <Setter.Value>
            <tk:RichTextBoxFormatBar />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately the problem remains.